# Problema para desplegar los datos número de sillas y millas en método heredado y sobrescrito

Tags: java, herencia

Tengo la clase base abstracta Car que tiene el método abstracto sin implementar,  abstract public String getMileage();

```
public abstract class Car {
protected boolean isSedan;
protected String seats;
protected int milead;
public Car(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
    this.isSedan = isSedan;
    this.seats = seats;
}

public Car(int milead) {
   this.milead = milead;
```

}

```
public boolean getIsSedan() {
    return this.isSedan;
}

public String getSeats() {
    return this.seats;
}

abstract public String getMileage();

public void setMileage(int milead) {
this.milead = milead;
```

}

```
public void printCar(String name) {
    System.out.println( 
      "A " + name + " is " + (this.getIsSedan() ? "" : "not ") 
        + "Sedan, is " + this.getSeats() + "-seater, and has a mileage of around "
        + this.getMileage() + ".");
}
```

}

Me daban inicialmente la clase sin tener un constructor con un parámetro entero pero yo lo deduje que se debía definir por la ejecución del programa, igual el método que a continuación muestro tampoc lo daban, no se si se podía definir:

```
 public void setMileage(int milead) {
    this.milead = milead;
  }
```

Y como era una clase abstracta con su método abstracto implemente ese método enm todas las subclases:

```
public class HondaCity extends Car{
 int mileage;
 public HondaCity(boolean isSedan, String seats, int Mileage){
     super(isSedan, seats);
     this.mileage = Mileage;
 }

public HondaCity(int mileage) {
    super(mileage);
}

 @Override
  public String getMileage()
    {
        return String.valueOf(this.mileage); 
    }
```

}

```
public class  InnovaCrysta extends Car{
 int mileage;
 public InnovaCrysta(boolean isSedan, String seats,int mileage){
     super(isSedan, seats);
     this.mileage = mileage;
 }
 
  public InnovaCrysta(int mileage) {
    super(mileage);
}
 
 @Override
  public String getMileage()
    {
         return String.valueOf(this.mileage); 
    }
```

}

```
public class WagonR extends Car{
 int mileage;

public WagonR(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
    super(isSedan, seats);
}

public WagonR(int mileage) {
    super(mileage);
}

 @Override
  public String getMileage()
    {
         return String.valueOf(this.mileage); 
    }
```

}

```
public class CarInheritance {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int carType = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
    int carMileage = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
    
    if (carType == 0){
        Car wagonR;
        wagonR = new WagonR(carMileage);
        wagonR.printCar("WagonR");
    }
    
    if(carType == 1){
        Car hondaCity = new HondaCity(carMileage);
        hondaCity.printCar("HondaCity");
    }
    
    if(carType == 2){
        Car innovaCrysta = new InnovaCrysta(carMileage);
        innovaCrysta.printCar("InnovaCrysta");
    }
}
```

}

Pero al correr el programa donde el primer dato ingresado es el tipo de carro y el siguiente dato es el kilometraje ne millas, no despliega el valor de millas, tampoco me queda claro como debía pasar el número de sillas del carro ya que en el código que daban no se ingresaba ese dato por consola, era un ejercicio de Hackerrank.

[image: Planteamiento del ejercicio]

[image: Salida de la ejecución del código]

Comment: @lobos,  la clase principal que ejecuta la daban tal cual aparece, no mostraban un constructor donde se pasaban los 3 parámetros, solo un constructor con los 2 parámetros:  public Car(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
    this.isSedan = isSedan;
    this.seats = seats;
}

Answer (score 1):

> Me daban inicialmente la clase sin tener un constructor con un
> parámetro entero pero yo lo deduje que se debía definir por la
> ejecución del programa, igual el método que a continuación muestro
> tampoc lo daban, no se si se podía definir

No es necesario ese constructor en la clase `Car`,los constructores de las clases hijas pueden tener ese parámetro y pasarlo a la clase padre. Tampoco es necesario el `setMileage(int)`

> Y como era una clase abstracta con su método abstracto implemente ese
> método enm todas las subclases

Eso está correcto.

> Pero al correr el programa donde el primer dato ingresado es el tipo
> de carro y el siguiente dato es el kilometraje ne millas, no despliega
> el valor de millas, tampoco me queda claro como debía pasar el número
> de sillas del carro ya que en el código que daban no se ingresaba ese
> dato por consola, era un ejercicio de Hackerrank.

El número de sillas se ingresa en el constructor de las clases hijas y luego se asigna a la clase padre. Imagino que pueden ser valores aleatorios si el problema no los define. No muestra el valor de las millas porque lo estás guardando en las clases hijas y tiene que guardarse en el padre.

Lo que menciono arriba lo ejemplifico con el siguiente código, usé solo una implementación por simplicidad:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Car wagonR;
        wagonR = new WagonR(true, "4", 1000);
        wagonR.printCar("WagonR");
     }
}

 abstract class Car {
     protected boolean isSedan;
     protected String seats;
     protected int milead;
     public Car(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
         this.isSedan = isSedan;
         this.seats = seats;
     }
     // esto no va, el valor se asignará desde una clase hija
     /*public Car(int milead) {
         this.milead = milead;
     }*/

     public boolean getIsSedan() {
         return this.isSedan;
     }

     public String getSeats() {
         return this.seats;
     }

     abstract public String getMileage();

     public void printCar(String name) {
         System.out.println(
             "A " + name + " is " + (this.getIsSedan() ? "" : "not ") +
             "Sedan, is " + this.getSeats() + "-seater, and has a mileage of around " +
             this.getMileage() + ".");
     }
 }

  class WagonR extends Car {
      // int mileage; esto no va, esta clase hereda la propiedad `mileage`
      // de la clase padre

     // el constructor recibe el valor de mileage
      public WagonR(boolean isSedan, String seats, int mileage) {
          super(isSedan, seats);
          // aquí se guarda el valor de mileage en la clase padre
          this.milead = mileage;
      }

      // esto no va, pasar el valor de mileage en el otro constructor
      /*public WagonR(int mileage) {
          super(mileage);
      }*/

      @Override
      public String getMileage() {
          return String.valueOf(this.milead);
      }
  }
```

---

**Actualización.**

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Car wagonR;
        wagonR = new WagonR(true, "4", 1000);
        wagonR.printCar("WagonR");
     }
}

 abstract class Car {
     protected boolean isSedan;
     protected String seats;
     public Car(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
         this.isSedan = isSedan;
         this.seats = seats;
     }
     // esto no va, el valor se asignará desde una clase hija
     /*public Car(int milead) {
         this.milead = milead;
     }*/

     public boolean getIsSedan() {
         return this.isSedan;
     }

     public String getSeats() {
         return this.seats;
     }

     abstract public String getMileage();

     public void printCar(String name) {
         System.out.println(
             "A " + name + " is " + (this.getIsSedan() ? "" : "not ") +
             "Sedan, is " + this.getSeats() + "-seater, and has a mileage of around " +
             this.getMileage() + ".");
     }
 }

  class WagonR extends Car {
      int mileage;

     // el constructor recibe el valor de mileage
      public WagonR(boolean isSedan, String seats, int mileage) {
          super(isSedan, seats);
          // aquí se guarda el valor de mileage en la clase padre
          this.mileage = mileage;
      }

      // esto no va, pasar el valor de mileage en el otro constructor
      /*public WagonR(int mileage) {
          super(mileage);
      }*/

      @Override
      public String getMileage() {
          return String.valueOf(this.mileage);
      }
  }
```

Comment: @tobos, creo que el atributo mileag no lo tenían definido en la clase padre, solo dfinian ese método abstract public String getMileage(); pero no recuerdo, estoy casí seguro que no se definía ese atributo.

Comment: De acuerdo, agregué una actualización moviendo la propiedad `mileage` a la clase hija. Respondiendo a tu comentario de arriba: el constructor de `Car` no se ha modificado, siempre tiene 2 parámetros. El que tiene tres parámetros es el de la clase hija.

Comment: hay forma de contactarte.

Comment: Sí, podemos hablar en este chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129596/questions